# MassTransit - Producer -> Consumer -> Producer

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to receive the response from consumer but I am getting a request timeout exception. I thought that the producer would get the response back but it's timing out unfortunately. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Can anybody help me? I'm stuck on this for a while now.

Here is the code I am using:

Program.cs (Producer)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MassTransit;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Rsi.LogiX.Engine.Contracts;

namespace GettingStarted
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        // By default, sagas are in-memory, but should be changed to a durable
                        // saga repository.
                        x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

                        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                        //x.AddMediator(cfg => { })
                        x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddRequestClient<HelloResponse>(new Uri($"queue:queuenname3"));
                        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            
                            cfg.Host("ConnectionString");
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);                            
                        });                       
                    });
                    
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.RemoveMassTransitHostedService();
                });
    }
}
```

Worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    public Worker(IBus bus, ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await _bus.Publish(new HelloMessage()
                {
                    Name = "NewWorld",
                }, stoppingToken);

                var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
                var scopedServiceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var requestClient = scopedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestClient<HelloResponse>>();
                
                // var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<HelloResponse>(new { "world" }, stoppingToken);

                var response = await requestClient.GetResponse<HelloResponse>(new
                {
                    Name = "NewWorld"
                }, stoppingToken);

                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Encountered an exception " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs (Consumer code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MassTransit;
using Company.Consumers;

namespace ConsumerCode
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        // By default, sagas are in-memory, but should be changed to a durable
                        // saga repository.
                        x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

                        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

                        x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
                        x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
                        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                        {

                            cfg.Host("ConnectionString");
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queuenname1", e =>
                            {
                                e.Consumer<HelloConsumer>(context); // Register your consumer for the message
                            });
                        });
                        
                    });
                });
    }
}
```

Consumer.cs

```
namespace Company.Consumers
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MassTransit;
    
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    using Rsi.LogiX.Engine.Contracts;

    public class HelloConsumer :
        IConsumer<HelloMessage>
    {
        readonly ILogger<HelloConsumer> _logger;

        public HelloConsumer(ILogger<HelloConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<HelloMessage> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello {Name}", context.Message.Name);

            var response = new HelloResponse
            {
                MyResponse = "This is a response for the message",
                IsTrue=true,
            };

            await context.RespondAsync(response);
            
        }
    }
}
```